# Error MY-000067 - unknown variable 'validate-password=FORCE_PLUS_PERMANENT'

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I'm struggling with password valaidity settings in 8.0.28. In this version component is in use instead of plugin.

Which means password validity component installed via:

```
INSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';
```

and seems it's okay as I can get result from mysql.component table:

```
mysql-test03 mysql> select * from mysql.component;
+--------------+--------------------+------------------------------------+
| component_id | component_group_id | component_urn                      |
+--------------+--------------------+------------------------------------+
|            2 |                  2 | file://component_validate_password |
+--------------+--------------------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But if I try to use related config options like

```
validate-password=FORCE_PLUS_PERMANENT
validate_password_length=14
validate_password_mixed_case_count=1
validate_password_number_count=1
validate_password_special_char_count=1
validate_password_policy=MEDIUM
```

I get this error and server does not start.

```
[ERROR] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'validate-password=FORCE_PLUS_PERMANENT'.
```

**For me seems component loads later than my.cnf parsed. And this way all of validate-password related settings change to invalid option.**

I tried to create some kind of manifest file mysqld.my to load this component but doesn't work either.

```
[root@mysql-test03 sbin]# cat mysqld.my
{
  "components": "file://component_validate_password"
}
```

What would be the solution here?

Thank you in advance,
Daniel

Comment: See [item 3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/validate-password-transitioning.html).

Comment: Is a plugin involved?

Comment: @mustaccio: as I wrote my.cnf options not work despite component in use. I saw that page. Actually I tried everything which described there.

Comment: @RickJames: plugin will be removed later so I'm using component instead of plugin. But now seems solution would be if I initiate SET PERSIST <foo> type option adjustment after database restarted and component loaded. (I need to do this once when I'm installing mysql. Btw it's an automated mysql deployment). Thanks.

Comment: "I tried everything which described there" -- no you did not, clearly. Particularly this part: "Those settings are appropriate for the plugin, but must be modified to apply to the component. To adjust the option file, omit the `--validate-password` option (it applies only to the plugin, not the component), and modify the system variable references from no-dot names appropriate for the plugin to dotted names appropriate for the component".

Comment: @mustaccio ehh yes you're right. Somehow I missed that part. Thanks. :)